# Create nested JSON from MariaDB datas using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, mariadb

I need help.
I have 3 tables.
1. post_table with columns : id_post, post_text.
2. attach_picture with column : id_picture, picture_name, id_post.
3. comment_table with column : id_comment, comment_text, id_post.

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'postingan');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else {
    echo "success";
  }

$postinganlist_array  = array();
$postingan_array = array();
$image_array = array();
$comment_array = array();
$fetch_postingan = mysqli_query($mysqli, 
    "SELECT id_post, post_text FROM post_table")
 or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
while ($row_postingan = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_postingan)){
$postingan_array['id'] = $row_postingan['id_post'];
$postingan_array['text'] = $row_postingan['post_text'];
$postingan_array['image']=array();
$postingan_array['comment']=array();

$fetch_images = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_picture, picture_name FROM attach_picture WHERE id_post = ".$row_postingan['id_post']."") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
while ($row_image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_images)) {
    $image_array['id']=$fetch_images['id_picture'];
    $image_array['pict']=$fetch_images['picture_name'];
    array_push($postingan_array['image'], $image_array);
}
$fetch_comments = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_comment, comment_text FROM comment_table WHERE id_post = ".$row_postingan['id_post']."") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
while ($row_comment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_comments)) {
    $comment_array['id']=$fetch_comments['id_comment'];
    $comment_array['comment']=$fetch_comments['comment_text'];
    array_push($postingan_array['comment'], $comment_array);
}
array_push($postinganlist_array, $postingan_array);}
$jsonData = json_encode(($postinganlist_array));
echo $jsonData;
?>
```

The output is like

```
success
Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\get.php on line 36 

Warning: mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\get.php on line 37
```

line 36 : ("SELECT id_post, post_text FROM post_table")
line 37 : (or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

My expected result is like

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "text": "Good morning all",
    "image": 
    {
        "id": "1",
        "pict": "morning.jpg"
    }
    "comment": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "comment": "Nice picture"
    }
    {
        "id": "2",
        "comment": "Thank you"
    }
    ]

    "id": "2",
    "text": "This is my new project",
    "image": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "pict": "splassreen.jpg"
        }
        {
            "id": "3",
            "pict": "main.jpg"
        }
    ]
    "comment": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "comment": "Great app"
        }
        {
            "id": "4",
            "comment": "Amazing"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `code` you have used

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'postingan');

$fetch_postingan = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_post, post_text FROM post_table") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$fetch_images = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_picture, picture_name FROM attach_picture WHERE id_post = ".$row_postingan['id_post']."") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$fetch_comments = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_comment, comment_text FROM comment_table WHERE id_post = ".$row_postingan['id_post']."") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

`mysqli_query` uses `connection string`. You have entered `$mysqli` which should have been `$con`. Your query must be as below:

```
$fetch_postingan = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id_post, post_text FROM post_table") or die(mysqli_error($con));

$fetch_images = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id_picture, picture_name FROM attach_picture WHERE id_post = ".$row_postingan['id_post']."") or die(mysqli_error($con));

$fetch_comments = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id_comment, comment_text FROM comment_table WHERE id_post = ".$row_postingan['id_post']."") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: it solve my problem. but the result is linear not like what i want like this success[{"id":"1","text":"great view","image":[{"id":"1","pict":"pict_1"},{"id":"2","pict":"pict_2"}],"comment":[{"id":"1","comment":"that's amazing"},{"id":"2","comment":"of course, the best"},{"id":"3","comment":"wish me there"}]},{"id":"2","text":"happy breakfast","image":[],"comment":[{"id":"4","comment":"yes, happy breakfast"},{"id":"5","comment":"hehe"}]},{"id":"3","text":"good night everybody","image":[],"comment":[]}] what code must i add to make it looks good?